# Как проверить открыт ли SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-search-view

Создал меню в `Toolbar` с элементом `SearchView`. В логике приложения возникла потребность проверить открыт ли `SearchView` и в случае если открыт - закрыть его. Пробовал так

```
if(searchItem.isActionViewExpanded())
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
```

Comment: А что возвращает `searchItem.isActionViewExpanded()`? Тут надо понять что именно не работает, проверка или все же сворачивание.

Comment: searchView.isIconified() по сути норм решение, но если к пример работать с катомным, возможно придется придумывать что-то свое, обычно Tag достаточно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(searchView != null && !searchView.isIconified()) {
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setIconified(true);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Работает :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchView view = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
if (view != null) {
    view.setQuery("", false);
}
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
```